# how to get all files being accessed by a process using c#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, service, window

I am trying to get list of process and accessed files list of each process by processid.
I am getting error:Unable to find an entry point named ‘RtlCopyMemory’ in DLL ‘kernel32.dll

```
int nHandleInfoSize = 0x10000;
IntPtr ipHandlePointer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(nHandleInfoSize);
int nLength = 0;
IntPtr ipHandle = IntPtr.Zero;

while ((nStatus = Win32API.NtQuerySystemInformation(CNST_SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION, ipHandlePointer, nHandleInfoSize, ref nLength)) == STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH)
{
    nHandleInfoSize = nLength;
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ipHandlePointer);
    ipHandlePointer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(nLength);
}

byte[] baTemp = new byte[nLength];
Win32API.CopyMemory(baTemp, ipHandlePointer, (uint)nLength);// Getting error on this
```

[This](https://bitbucket.org/hintdesk/dotnet-get-all-files-being-accessed-by-a-process-in-64-bits/src/0dd5bcf48891?at=default) is the reference link I have used.

kindly help me to resolved issue.

Comment: Are you using a 64 bit process? That library is marked as _"get all files being accessed by a process **in 64 bits**"_ and as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47016390/43846) says _"whether RtlCopyMemory is available is dependent on your platform … On 64-bit Windows RtlCopyMemory actually exists as an export, which is why that works for .NET Core (and 64-bit .NET Framework as well)"_

Comment: @stuartd - yes i am using 64 bit process